# Notification when a favorite was closed or deleted

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, bookmarks, deleted-questions

I mark a question as favorite when I feel it's important for me to keep it for future reference, and stay informed of the updates/new content.

So, if it gets closed, probably I want to vote for reopen. Or if it gets deleted, I want to keep a local copy just in case.

So, is there any notification about the status change for my favorites (such as when the content is modified)? If the answer is no ... Could it be implemented?

Comment: @Benny I tagged my question [discussion] and not [feature-request] because I'm not really sure if such a notification already exists.

Comment: Note: [the Bookmarks feature (which is what "Favorites" was renamed to) has been replaced by the Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/335251). You may want to edit your post to focus on the Saves feature instead.