# Notification when your question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notice of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion)

Related: [Notification when a favorite was closed or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77092/notification-when-a-favorite-was-closed-or-deleted)

I'm pretty sure I had a question of mine deleted here on meta which I'm fine with. It was a bad question.

What I'm not so fine with is that there is no notification that its been deleted. This would be especially confusing for someone new to the site.

If your question is deleted for whatever reason please make it so that there is a notification along with a reason. Otherwise the software just appears buggy.

*As a related note I which I could read the answers to that question again.*

Comment: Sorry I honestly did try to find a previous question as I was sure it had been asked.