# Could I be notified when a question I answered is deleted?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

I poured my heart out to write a great answer to a question, and I earned a gold badge for it. I'm so proud of the answer that I've even linked to it on the web in several places.

To my surprise, I discovered that the question had been closed without notifying me, and that it had been deleted without notifying me.

Since there already is [a question about notifications for closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/162948), this question is specifically about deletions.

Please could I be notified whenever a question that I posted an answer to is deleted? Especially if my answer is long, or earned lots of upvotes. I want to at least be able to fix any links to that question, and maybe convert that answer into a blog post or something, because I really do think it is making the Internet a better place.

Some high-rep users have already found the deleted question that caused me to discover this issue. But I want to be clear that I'm not trying to generate a discussion about whether the deletion was justified or not, I'm pointing out that I was never notified of the deletion, and I think I should have been.

My question is slightly different from [this apparent duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89402/notification-when-your-question-is-deleted), as I want to be notified when a question of my answer is deleted, not necessarily when my question has been deleted.

Comment: FYI, you get to keep any badges you earned for that question, and if your answer had +3 or more and was posted more than 90 days before deletion you also get to keep the reputation. So while annoying, you don't really lose anything.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, I have ran across many of these, so whenever I see such questions I tend to favourite them so I can still find them if they get deleted. But I am getting far away from OP's request, which I by the way support.

Comment: I deliberately did not want to mention the specific question, because this post is about the fact that I was not notified. It isn't about whether the deletion was justified or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification when your question is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89402/notification-when-your-question-is-deleted)

Comment: @ben: I'd say that this is different. This is asking for notification when you have an answer on someone else's question that gets deleted.

Comment: Sorry for pointing to the specific deleted answer of yours. I have deleted my comment to prevent the question to go out of your desired scope.

Comment: By the way, that specific question has been undeleted and locked.

Answer (score 24):

I would generally be in favor of this. Deletions are less frequent than closures, so we shouldn't need to worry about "notification overload".

A happy side effect of this could be alerting people who habitually answer off-topic questions, and maybe they'll stop.