# Answer disappeared without any clue about the reason

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I came to a question in StackOverflow about how to sort a data array with different fields and render into an html table using JavaScript.

I provided an answer posting a function and some links (a working example, and some references where the author could find more extra information or alternatives). After a while, I received a comment from the author in my answer saying something like "works great, thank you". I was then expecting my answer to be accepted by the author, but instead a couple of minutes later I found the question to have been deleted (and thus my answer too) without any further comment, reason or notice provided.

I would like to share some thoughts about this fact.

- How am I supposed to know that an author actually deleted his question, if my reputation is lower than 10k (and probably always will be) and not something else has happened?
- Was something wrong regarding my answer, that was related? And even if there was, I would expect the answer to be maybe downvoted.
- Shouldn't the system notify users when an answer of them is deleted?
- I found the overall situation a bit annoying and showing not much respect to the people who put some effort (maybe little, maybe more) to deal with somebody's question. To just leave without providing any justification or clue (maybe just a comment).

Of course, I will not stop try contributing to the site as I can, I am just expressing my thoughts.

Comment: You can go to your profile, click the answers tab and then click "recent deleted answers". The deleted answer might be there and should still be visible to you.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178570/user-quickly-deletes-own-question-once-they-have-received-an-answer

Comment: deletion notification: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290302/could-i-be-notified-when-a-question-i-answered-is-deleted

Comment: Thank you @rene, I found my deleted answer there, the author deleted her question indeed. And this, after commenting that " Great solution, thank you very much...". A little weird.

Comment: If both question and answer are of great value you could flag for a moderator. care to post a link here to your answer so I can advice if flagging would be helpful?

Comment: Thank you for the links you provided, I am reading them carefully. I don't think the question and the answer are of _great_ value, mostly a simple _problem - solution_ kind of stuff. I won't raise a flag, moderators already have much work to deal with. And if the author hadn't commented a _Thanks_, I wouldn't bother either.

Comment: The mod team on SO has enough hands to keep the mod queue at bay. If the OP that deleted their question have an habit of the same behavior more users might be impacted. It simply is not the kind of behavior we agree on is OK.

Comment: Do note that there are in fact measures to stop question authors from deleting answered questions: one can't delete their question if it has multiple answers or a single answer with at least one upvote. This does mean that if the author pounces just in time so that the answer doesn't get a chance to be upvoted, it will be allowed. There exists [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135538/) to prevent authors from deleting their answered questions within 24 hours of their being answered, which you can support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How am I supposed to know that an author actually deleted his question, if my reputation is lower than 10k (and probably always will be) and not something else has happened?

You can monitor your recently deleted [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers) using the 
"recently deleted question/answer" link at the bottom of both lists.

You can always view the deleted question if you have answered, even if you do not have 10k rep.

> Was something wrong regarding my answer, that was related? And even if there was, I would expect the answer to be maybe downvoted.

In this case the author of the question deleted their post.

> Shouldn't the system notify users when an answer of them is deleted?

Answered here [When a user has one of their questions or answers deleted, why don't you notify them about the deletion, and send the removed content by email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209694/when-a-user-has-one-of-their-questions-or-answers-deleted-why-dont-you-notify)

> I found the overall situation a bit annoying and showing not much respect to the people who put some effort (maybe little, maybe more) to deal with somebody's question. To just leave without providing any justification or clue (maybe just a comment).

We agree with you. In this case, bring it to our attention by flagging the question for moderator attention explaining that the author deleted the question after you posted an answer.

I've undeleted [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56279659) now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of the link to show my deleted answers. And for the immediate action. You have my respect.